# Kafka consumer not reading all the records

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am facing an issue for reading all the records from Kafka topic. I am expecting to read 3000+ records but I am getting only 1700 records. I am passing `max.poll.records` value 5000 by default.
I want to read all the records from the topic and return it as json.

Below is the code that we're using for extracting the data (the listener implementation). Ideally the onMessage method would get the full result set inside the List of Consumer records. Unfortunately for bigger requests the results are extracted partially - in our test example we have 3888 records written to a Kafka topic (with a single partition) and we want to extract all of them at once when performing the GET request. When tracking the amount of results when the onMessage method is being triggered we see only 1792. We've tried playing around with the kafka configuration - setting min and max bytes and poll records but none of them seem to work - the batch still only reads a certain subset at a time. Currently we're looking for a workaround for this to enable us to get the full set of records from a topic. Using synchronized queues and so on didn't give the desired result as well so if anyone has any suggestions we would be grateful since we're running out of ideas on how to make this work.

```
public class PermutationResultListener implements BatchMessageListener<String, String> {
private SynchronousQueue<List<String>> responsesQueue = new SynchronousQueue<>();

@Overridepublic void onMessage(List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> results) {
    log.info("Permutation Listener invoked - received {} results", results.size());
    List<String> mappedResults = results.stream().map(res -> res.value()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    try {
        responsesQueue.put(mappedResults);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        log.error("Error putting permutation results into queue: {}", e.getMessage());
    }
}

public String getResults() throws InterruptedException{
    
    return responsesQueue.take().toString();
}
}
```

```
    private final int MAX_RECORD_POLL_DEFAULT = 5000;

    public Map<String, Object> getConfiguration() {

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaBootstrapServers);
        map.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, kafkaGroupId);
        map.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        map.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        map.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        map.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
        int byteSizeForRequest = 40000 * amountOfRecords;
        map.put(ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG, byteSizeForRequest);
        map.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG, byteSizeForRequest);
        map.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, getMaxAmountOfRecords());
        return map;
    }
```

is there anything I am missing here?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Does your topic have 5000+ records to read from?

Comment: Can you share your code where you are actually counting the records?

Comment: @Umeshwaran My topic have more than 3000+ records . I am using BatchMessageListener.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I can see using postman the total number of records .

Comment: I don't think this is possible as the broker will decide when it's ok to send the data as long as it respects `fetch.min.bytes`, `fetch.max.bytes`, `max.partition.fetch.bytes`, `max.poll.records` and the other parameters. The only way to specify This is very odd use case for kafka (similar to using a hammer to eat soup if I might say). You could try setting `fetch.min.bytes` to `byteSizeForRequest` and see if that works, but this could be clunky.

Comment: @Augusto I have tried `fetch.min.bytes` to `byteSizeForRequest` but it didn't work.

Comment: Postman doesn't have a Kafka consumer plugin, last I checked. Without seeing your Java API code, I wouldn't trust that number. As indicated, putting Kafka consumer behind any blocking HTTP request is not a good pattern to be following, but you still need to show the code for it

Comment: @OneCricketeer the code is mentioned below , we are using BatchMessageListener

Comment: What do you mean below? Do you and LisekKL work together? Your code should be part of the question as a [mcve]. Regardless, I commented below with problems with that solution

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yeah she is working with me. I have updated the question . Can you please provide the problems with the solution here. Thank you

Comment: @OneCricketeer we're using only 1 partition and 1 topic at a time - after saving the data we confirm that there are 3888 records available within that topic and partition - for now we don't use scaling and have only a single instance from which we want to retrieve all results

Comment: Just because there are that many messages in the topic, doesn't mean your app will always consume all those events. For instance, if you're committing offsets at any point, and your app restarts, then it'll only consume from that committed point. Secondly, if you call the REST API while the consumer has a non zero lag, then you'll obviously not get all the results. Overall, I'd suggest you use Kafka Connect externally to write the data to a persistent database, assuming that you have one, then build your API  to query that rather than wait for the consumer to finish every time your api starts

Comment: @OneCricketeer The Auto-commit is off to make sure Kafka won't do any intermediate offset committing. We always start reading from offset 0 and only 1 consumer is consuming the messages from topic.
We are using 1 consumer , 1 topic and 1 partition and we need to a batch extract for all the messages from the given topic. It's working for smaller requests using the BatchMessageListener but when running a listener for given 3888 or higher (we can lookup the offsets in kafka - it will be 0:3888) records after the save has been processed,

Comment: @OneCricketeer it somehow slices the data and reads it partially instead of processing full 3888, so we're looking for a config / different listener / so that we can force the full data to be extracted in one READ call.

Comment: Have you tried creating a regular KafkaConsumer  instance without Spring? Have you looked at how the Kafka REST Proxy works for doing the exact same thing?